# JavaScript - add elements inside another always before last one

Tags: dom

I have next sctructure

```
<section>
   <article>
   <article>
   <button>
</section>
```

How to add new `<article>` elements (for example 3) inside the `<section>` but before `<button>` using JavaScript?
Thanks

Comment: I found answer:
insertAdjacentHTML

Answer (score 0):

You can use `querySelector` in conjunction with `:last-of-type` CSS pseudo-class:

```
document.querySelector(`section > article:last-of-type`);
```